# How to select corresponding value in two data sets using matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a two datasets (`x,y`) in in table:

```
x = [4.14;5.07;3.61;4.07;3.68;4.13;3.95;3.88;5.41;6.14]
y = [69.78;173.07;19.28;32.88;15.87;53.73;41.69;35.14;228.08;267.11];
tb = table(x,y)
edges = linspace(30, 0, 61);
```

Based on this I have written following program

```
for k = 1:length(x)
    New(k) = find(x(k)>edges,1,'last');
end
```

I want to see datasets `y`  which satisfying condition of of above `x` values.

Comment: I do not really understand, are you saying that you want histogram, or a pdf? Or some other data representation? Or is the problem that you want to find mean and variance? Please edit the question (by pressing the edit button) and clarify.

Comment: Ok let me start with step by step problem. See the 1st edit problem

Comment: Ok this does not make much more sense. The loop you provide does only return the last element or an empty matrix. I assume you want to check the other way `<`? Anyway I am still not sure what you are after. It seems as if you would like to set the x values in a certain bin. I am unable yo see how this relates to `y` though. _I want to see datasets 'y' which satisfying condition of of above 'x' values._ . This condition does not make sense since there is no condition for `x`. There is no true or false only logical indexing. Could you give the name of the datastructure you want?

Comment: so you want to see where in your `edges` the `x` value would be and then you want to do something with the corresponding `y`, but what do you want to have in the end? Or do you want to create "bins" for edges and the put the `y` values in the bin where the `x` value would be compared to `edges`?